# Prove that the system of linear equations represented by $Ax=b$ is consistent for all $m\times 1$ column vectors $b$ iff rank of $A$ is $m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I'm really confused about this proof.

I am thinking start from why $Ax=b$ being consistent for all $b$ only can happen if $m$ is less than or equal to $n$ but I don't know how to express this in terms of proof style.

$A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: hint: The rank of A is the dimension of the vector space spanned by its columns.

Comment: What is $n$?  Please define your variables.  Do we know $A$ is square?  You can take a set of $m$  basis vectors, note that there must be a solution for each of them, and use linearity for one direction.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. A is a mxn matrix

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try proving the negations. That is, prove: the system $Ax=b$ is inconsistent for some $b\in\Bbb K^m$ if and only if $rank (A)<m$. Note that the negation is that $rank (A)\neq m$, but since $A$ has size $m\times n$, the most that $rank (A)$ could be is $m$.